# get the final value nearest to 50

Tags: php

I have made a calculation now when ever the final total is came up within the invoice I want to be be given as nearest to 50 like if you round 420 the correct way to round to nearest x50 the result is 400, the formula round to 450. 
If you round 430 the correct rounding to nearest 50 would be 450. Now the problem is that I am weak in maths so I am unable to judge how do I do this in php is there I searched many everyone is explaining but not telling me how do I implement it in the formula

Comment: Have you searched for it?

Comment: `round(n / 50) * 50`?

Comment: What about `425` ?

Comment: @user2486 OP uses words like "correct rounding" and "nearest" so normal rounding is probably what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide by 50 and round the value, then multiply with 50.

```
$input =420;

Echo round($input/50)*50;
```

https://3v4l.org/SYoKk

Comment: Thank you so much for the help great thumbs up for you